# Do the action blocks of an ALTER TABLE statement run atomically?

Tags: postgresql, transaction, alter-table

In Postgres, [`ALTER TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-altertable.html) can accept multiple `action` forms, separated by a comma. 
 For example:

```sql
ALTER TABLE mytable
  DROP CONSTRAINT pkey,
  ADD CONSTRAINT pkey PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX myindex;
```

Will the `action`s be executed atomically somehow?  Or does the statement need to be wrapped in a transaction to ensure all `action`s take effect in unison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every SQL statement is run inside a transaction. At minimum (and by default) each statement runs in its own transaction.

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-begin.html) says:

> By default (without `BEGIN`), PostgreSQL executes transactions in “autocommit” mode, that is, each statement is executed in its own transaction and a commit is implicitly performed at the end of the statement (if execution was successful, otherwise a rollback is done).

So either both actions succeed, or both are rolled back.